# Is it possible to calculate dots per degree of visual angle without the object size?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

Suppose i have been given the reading distance of 12 inches and the dpi is say around 600. Is there anyway to calculate the dots per visual angle without the object size or any other information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the size of the object is not important -- you can consider it to be an infinite plane of pixels extending in all directions at 600 DPI. This works because you want the dots *per degree*. It's like asking for density (mass *per volume*) of an object instead of the total mass - you need to know the size for the total mass, but not for the density.

So the answer to your problem would be the area (in square inches) of the base of a 12" tall cone with a 1-degree point, times the DPI.